# 0x800a139e - JavaScript runtime error: [ng:areq] Argument 'timesheetListCtrl' is not a function, got undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I cant get this simple angular app to work. I know I am probably doing something silly. If anyone can help I would greatly appreciate it.When I run it I'm getting the following error:

0x800a139e - JavaScript runtime error: [ng:areq] Argument 'timesheetListCtrl' is not a function, got undefined

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="en">

    <!-- Style sheets -->
    <link href="Content/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>

<body ng-app="timesheetManagement">

    <div class="container">
        <div ng-include="'app/HTML/timesheetListView.html'"></div>
    </div>
    <!-- Library Scripts -->
    <script src="scripts/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/angular-resource.js"></script>
    <!-- Application Script -->
    <script src="app/app.js"></script>
    <!-- Services -->
    <script src="common/common.services.js"></script>
    <script src="common/timesheetResource.js"></script>
    <!-- Product Controllers -->
    <script src="app/HTML/"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

**timesheetListView.html**

```
<div class="panel panel-primary"
     ng-controller="timesheetListCtrl as vm">
    <div class="panel-heading"
         style="font-size:large">
        Product List
    </div>
```

**app.js**

```
(function () {
    "use strict";

    var timesheetManagement = angular
        .module("timesheetManagement",
                            ["common.services"]);

}());
```

**timesheetListCtrl.js**

```
(function () {
    "use strict";
    angular
        .module("timesheetManagement")
        .controller("timesheetListCtrl",
                     ["timesheetResource",  timesheetListCtrl]);

    function timesheetListCtrl(timesheetResource) {
        var vm = this;

        timesheetResource.query(function (data) {
            vm.timesheets = data
        });

    }
}());
```

Comment: include timesheetListCtrl.js in index.html

Comment: Im nearly embarrased! that was so glaringly obvious!! Thank you so much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, it turns out you have to include `timesheetListCtrl.js` in index.html